# How can I check if execv failed or not, and how to use perror

Tags: c

```
pid_t extraction = fork();
    
    switch(extraction){
        case -1 :
        printf("fork() failed\n");
        break;

        case 0 :
        for(int i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++){
            char* args[] = {"/usr/bin/tar","-C", cwd ,"-xvf", argv[i], NULL}; //Provide arguments for execution of tar
            execv("/usr/bin/tar", args);
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;

        default : {
            int status;
            wait(&status);
            printf("Child process terminated with status = %i\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
        }
```

So im a bit confused on how I can check my child exit status if execv didn't run. I might be misunderstanding a lot of things regarding errno and perror and how execv works. My understanding is if execv fails, it will return -1, which means the line exit(EXIT_SUCCESS) will never run, and thus -1 is returned to my int status.

If the code i provided above actually works the way it's intended, I want to try using perror too, just rewriting the default part of the switch statement:

```
defult: {
   int status;
   wait(&status);
   if(status != -1){
      printf("Extraction preformed successfully");
   }
   else{
      perror("Error");
   }
}
```

This is the extend of my knowledge, anyone that would like to fill in any holes I have about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where did your understanding come from? If `execv` succeeds, it will never return and `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` in your program won't be executed. On the other hand, if all calls of  `execv` fails, it will exit from the `for` loop and `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` will be executed.

Comment: Also [`execv`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) will return `-1`, not `0` as you says, when it fails.

Comment: @MikeCAT probs misread it from some where. So I should have `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` there to report failure of execv instead of `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`? Following on from this idea, if I'm waiting for a exit status from my child process, but `execv` returns nothing if it succeeds, and `exit(...)` doesn't run, what will my 'WEXITSTATUS(status)' return?

Comment: @MikeCATah yeah i meant -1 sorry

Comment: What is returned from the program `/usr/bin/tar` will be returned to `WEXITSTATUS(status)` when `execv` succeds.

Comment: Ahh ok, so how can I make use of perror or just errno?

Comment: `perrpr` should be used in your child process.

Comment: like `int error = execv("/usr/bin/tar", args");` then `if(error = -1){perror("Error")}` ?

Comment: `args"` should be `args` and `if(error = -1){perror("Error")}` should be `if(error == -1){perror("Error");}` or simply `perror("Error");` because `execv` returns only if it fails.

Comment: ahhhh i see, so I can basically forgo the whole int error and if checks and just throw perror() the line after my execv?

Comment: It's pointless to put execv in a loop. If execv succeeds, it never returns; the process is *replaced* with what is being execv'd. If you want to perform a loop of subtasks, you'll need to create children with fork().

Comment: You should normally use `execv(args[0], args);` unless you want to misname the process for devious reasons.  Your `wait()` statement should trap the PID of the dead child (in case some other child died instead of the one just launched — it can happen).  You analyze the exit status with `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WIFTERMSIG`, etc — defined in `<sys/wait.h>`.  You should always put some code after `execv()` to deal with the case where the execution fails.  It is horrid if the child continues thinking it is the parent process. You should generate an error and exit with failure.

Comment: For your particular task, i would suggest `system()` and forget about `fork()` and `execv()`, but i think you want to learn something.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: You can redirect `stderr` or `stdout` and parse it. You can create a shared memory region and write a status to it. This can then be read by your parent. You can create a signal handler and send a signal (but your executed program can do the same). You can exit with a particular status and check the exit code (but your executed program can do the same).